# how to use Time-based Pagination with Facebook graph api v2.x

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the link below said that we could get a time based paging result :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4

My problem is ,how could i make a request so can i received a result like that ?

anyone could help me , thanks anyway !

Comment: What have you considered, tried, and found the trouble to be?

Comment: i have tried to request like this way using graph api explore:[link](me?fields=likes.since(1420041600))  but i got all the result ,so i guess there must be  something wrong

Comment: The point being made here is to show the code that you have tried as well as explaining what has not worked for you and the expected result. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Time-based Pagination  which described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4
please give me a example . thanks again !@J0e3gan

Answer (score -1):

finally i find the answer is :
not all the node in Facebook open graph support time-based paging , such as likes 
the official example node which support it is feed
so you can get a time-based paging result if you send request like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me/feed?limit=20&&since= 1420041600
or :
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me/feed?limit=20&&until= 1420048600

dose anyone has a more specified answer about it ?